# Semantic bootstrap navbar - sass

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, compass-sass

Starting points:

- Using bootstrap-sass (compass)
- have the following html-markup (**can't change it**)

```
<div class="some">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="inactive">Item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="inactive">Item3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Is possible style the above (using the sass-bootstrap) as navbar without the "brand-logo" and without changing the html - e.g. semantically?

Comment: what do you mean by "brand-logo"? bootstrap class names?

Comment: This question is unclear, what are you trying to achieve? There is no `brand-logo` in your code. Please include more relevant code and better explain what you want the output to be.

Comment: @TinyGiant The question isn't very good  (missing what the OP already tried), but if someone knows twitter-bootstrap, he knows what is the "brand" in the navbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only style, just use the wanted styles like:

```
.some {
    @extend .navbar;
    @extend .navbar-inverse;
}
.some {
    ul {
        @extend .nav;
        @extend .navbar-nav;
        @extend .navbar-right;
        > li a.active {
            &,
            &:hover,
            &:focus {
                color: $navbar-inverse-link-active-color;
                background-color: $navbar-inverse-link-active-bg;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

E.g. the above will style your div/ul to get an right aligned inverse navbar - all styling is like in the bootstrap.

I not tested the javascript - it will probably fail, because it will search for the `navbar` - but the above for the simple styling works.

For the `li > a.active` part: i just copied it directly from the bootstrap-sass, it is needed because the bootstrap uses the `active` for the `li` element and not for the `a` element, so you need exactly style the `a.active`.

Also, it didn't collapses into the button, but only changes its layout to vertical list.

The "brand" will be automatically excluded, because it isn't in the markup.

Comment: Exactly for what i'm looking.

Answer (score 0):

I think we would need to see more of the code but if memory serves you are using the standard Twitter Bootstrap menu. If so you 'could' style this using the class and display none the Brand-logo that is in the code. If you can remove the brand logo from the HTML it would be easier